# fetch file list with details from ftp server using vba code and display in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I have written a macro to fetch files with details from ftp server but I am unable parse it from output file.
Or any other alternative would be great.

Thanks for help.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
f = "D:\FTPScript.txt"

Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim user As String
Dim Password As String
Dim vFile As String

vFTPServ = Sheet1.ftpHostTxt.Text
user = Sheet1.unmTxt.Text
Password = Sheet1.pwdTxt.Text
vFile = Sheet1.filePath.Text

    Open f For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Open "; vFTPServ
    Print #1, user
    Print #1, Password
    Print #1, "ascii"
    Print #1, "prompt"
    'Print #1, "put " & VREDET; vFile
    Print #1, "ls -block-size"
    Print #1, "disconnect"
    Print #1, "bye"
    Print #1, "exit"
    Close #1
    Shell "cmd /c C:\WINDOWS\system32\ftp.exe -i -s:D:\FTPScript.txt > D:\ftpuploadlog.txt", vbHide
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `ftp.exe` supports -block-size; however, for dumping the output of the ls command to a local file, you simply need to specify the file path as the local-file parameter for ls.

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#ls

Comment: i have succeeded dumping data to local file. Further I am unable to get recursive file list. I am not able to get file list from sub-directories.